# Connect to server using Nautilus and navigate to root catalog

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, ftp, sftp

I connect to server using Nautilus via SFTP. It opens home directory and not allows to go very root catalog. If I do the same connection using FAR commander from windows I also moved top home directory, but in this case I can navigate root catalog. How do the same in Nautilus that runs in Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't allow it? What happens if you hit Ctrl+L or select Go-->Location from the menu, and enter `/`?

Answer (score 2):

Although nautilus doesn't seem to present an easy way (such as a `..` item) to navigate up, even when 'Show Hidden Files' <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is enabled, you should be able to navigate up **provided that the configuration of the remote server does not forbid it, for example via a `chroot` jail**.

Probably the easiest way is to open the Location bar, either from the menu (`Go --> Enter Location...`) or using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> keyboard shortcut. Then enter the desired location e.g. `/` by typing in the bar.